# Skype DualPhone - Multiple Accounts

Tags: skype, phone

I have two Skype DualPhone 3088's. I signed in to Skype on one of the phone's, and it signed in to the account on both phone's.

What I've been trying to do is have one phone signed in to one Skype account and the other signed into another account.
I can't find anything to help on their website as when I browse to my specific product it redirects to their homepage.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? If so, can someone help explain how to do it?

Comment: Where do you define what your Skype account is on these phones?  The second phone must either have this information or it must be connected to your Skype account.  Once you figure out which one it is you can figure out the rest.

Comment: I go to Menu -> Status and then I can sign in (or if I've already signed in it lets me sign out). When I sign in on one phone it signs in to the same account on the other automatically. The same for when I sign out